# java catch indexoutofboundsexception

Tags: try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

i googled a lot, but I dont know why I am not able to catch the `indexoutofboundsexception` error. Can sombody tell me, whats my mistake?

```
try
{
    if (amountOfPlayers <= 15 && amountOfPlayers > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
            i++;
            System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
            String name = scanner.next();
            nameList.add(name);
        } while (i < amountOfPlayers);
    }
}
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Wrong input. Theres a maximum of 15 players allowed");
}
```

Comment: Theres a scanner before, asking how many Players want to play.

Comment: The error only appears, if u type 0 or more then 15.

Comment: What is supposed to throw the exception? `if` definitely doesn't (by itself) !

Comment: Im pretty new to java. So I cant tell sry

Comment: you either need to throw the exception yourself, see for example https://rollbar.com/guides/java-throwing-exceptions/ or you need to do something creating an exception. Like here accessing an array (or another object?) outside of its bounds, Say something like PlayerName[16] or PlayerName[i] with i == 16, for a PlayerName array of size 16, going from [0] to [15]

Comment: Okay. I´ll try it with the Array. Thanks for the fast and good response^^